# XSLT typograph

Tags: xslt, typography, divide

**Divide a large amount of text on an arbitrary number of equal parts.**

I probably already fed up with their stupid questions, but I have one more question.

I have a large piece of text

```
<p>
    Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
    totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, 
    explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit,
</p>
<p> 
    aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi 
    nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, 
    sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
    Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid 
    ex ea commodi consequatur? 
</p>
<p>
    Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, 
    vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio 
    dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas 
    molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt 
    mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. 
    Nam libero tempore, cum 
</p>
<p>
    soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, 
    omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis 
    aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. 
    Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur 
    aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</p>
<p>
    Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem 
    aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. 
    Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit,
</p>
<p>
    Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
    totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, 
    explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit,
</p>
<p> 
    aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi 
    nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, 
    sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
    Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid 
    ex ea commodi consequatur?
</p>
<p>
    Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, 
    vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio 
    dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et 
    quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia 
    deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita 
    distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum 
</p>
<p>
    soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, 
    omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut 
    rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. 
    Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur 
    aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</p>
<p>
    Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, 
    vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio 
    dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas 
    molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt 
    mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. 
    Nam libero tempore, cum 
</p>
<p>
    Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
    totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, 
    explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit,
</p>
<p>
    soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere 
    possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut 
    officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae 
    non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores 
    alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</p>
<p>
    Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam 
    rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, 
    explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit,
</p>
```

At the exit I need to divide the text on the "n" equal parts, so that in these parts was about the same amount of text. Then I these part are arranged in columns and the need for these columns look about the same height. Another condition: Tags you can break (I mean that if the tag "p" contains a lot of text, it can be divided into two parts, to bring in another column). I think this is a monumental task, I shall be grateful for any help.

I understand that XSLT is not typography tool. But is it possible divide the text into parts with the same number of characters in each part?

Comment: XSLT is not a typography tool. There is no way of knowing how wide a letter will render in your chosen font, so making it look a roughly equal amount of text is really difficult.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, I understand. But it is possible divide the text into parts with the same number of characters in each.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the `<p>` elements, or are you just looking for all of the words - equally divided?

Comment: @Mads Hansen Tags `<p>` should stay, but the tag `<p>` can be divided into parts, for example: `<p> soluta nobis est eligendceat, facere possimus </ p>` can be divided into `<p> soluta nobis est eligendceat, <p> </ p> facere possimus </ p>`

Comment: Why anyone would doubt this cannot be done with XSLT? I even don't remember when I did it for the first time. Since then I have been occupied with much more interesting and challenging tasks. Hint: do you want to use a generalized LR parser, written entirely in XSLT? Since I developed it I used it for a few specific parsers. One for JSON and one for XPath 2.0. Interested? :)

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, I will first try to understand your code, if there are questions, I will ask.

Comment: Dear @kalininew,

Never place your questions in "community wiki". No answer is awarded rep id it is in the community wiki. People seeing a question in the community wiki are less likely to reply.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I do not know. This will not do more.

Answer (score 2):

**Text justification with XSLT is possible** (I did it many years ago). Here is a small example that you can use as a base to carry out your complete task:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:str-split2lines-func="f:str-split2lines-func"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl ext str-split2lines-func"
>


   <xsl:import href="dvc-str-foldl.xsl"/>

   <!-- to be applied on text.xml -->

   <str-split2lines-func:str-split2lines-func/>

   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-lines">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="/*"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pLineLength" select="64"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" select="' &#9;&#10;&#13;'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="str-split-to-lines">
      <xsl:param name="pStr"/>
      <xsl:param name="pLineLength" select="60"/>
      <xsl:param name="pDelimiters" select="' &#9;&#10;&#13;'"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vsplit2linesFun"
                    select="document('')/*/str-split2lines-func:*[1]"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vrtfParams">
       <delimiters><xsl:value-of select="$pDelimiters"/></delimiters>
       <lineLength><xsl:copy-of select="$pLineLength"/></lineLength>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="vResult">
          <xsl:call-template name="dvc-str-foldl">
            <xsl:with-param name="pFunc" select="$vsplit2linesFun"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="$pStr"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pA0" select="ext:node-set($vrtfParams)"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:for-each select="ext:node-set($vResult)/line">
        <xsl:for-each select="word">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="str-split2lines-func:*" mode="f:FXSL">
      <xsl:param name="arg1" select="/.."/>
      <xsl:param name="arg2"/>

      <xsl:copy-of select="$arg1/*[position() &lt; 3]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$arg1/line[position() != last()]"/>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($arg1/*[1], $arg2)">
          <xsl:if test="string($arg1/word)">
             <xsl:call-template name="fillLine">
               <xsl:with-param name="pLine" select="$arg1/line[last()]"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pWord" select="$arg1/word"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pLineLength" select="$arg1/*[2]"/>
             </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$arg1/line[last()]"/>
          <word><xsl:value-of select="concat($arg1/word, $arg2)"/></word>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

      <!-- Test if the new word fits into the last line -->
    <xsl:template name="fillLine">
      <xsl:param name="pLine" select="/.."/>
      <xsl:param name="pWord" select="/.."/>
      <xsl:param name="pLineLength" />

      <xsl:variable name="vnWordsInLine" select="count($pLine/word)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vLineLength" 
       select="string-length($pLine) + $vnWordsInLine"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($vLineLength + string-length($pWord) 
                           > 
                            $pLineLength)">
          <line>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pLine/*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pWord"/>
          </line>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$pLine"/>
          <line>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pWord"/>
          </line>
          <word/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when performed on this XML document** (this is the original document that was used back then -- this cnn text can be traced back to 2003 or 2002):

```
<text>
Dec. 13 — As always for a presidential inaugural, security and surveillance were
extremely tight in Washington, DC, last January. But as George W. Bush prepared to
take the oath of office, security planners installed an extra layer of protection: a
prototype software system to detect a biological attack. The U.S. Department of
Defense, together with regional health and emergency-planning agencies, distributed
a special patient-query sheet to military clinics, civilian hospitals and even aid
stations along the parade route and at the inaugural balls. Software quickly
analyzed complaints of seven key symptoms — from rashes to sore throats — for
patterns that might indicate the early stages of a bio-attack. There was a brief
scare: the system noticed a surge in flulike symptoms at military clinics.
Thankfully, tests confirmed it was just that — the flu.
</text>
```

**correctly performs justification of every line to the desired width of no more than 64** The result is:

```
Dec. 13 — As always for a presidential inaugural, security and 
surveillance were extremely tight in Washington, DC, last 
January. But as George W. Bush prepared to take the oath of 
office, security planners installed an extra layer of 
protection: a prototype software system to detect a biological 
attack. The U.S. Department of Defense, together with regional 
health and emergency-planning agencies, distributed a special 
patient-query sheet to military clinics, civilian hospitals and 
even aid stations along the parade route and at the inaugural 
balls. Software quickly analyzed complaints of seven key 
symptoms — from rashes to sore throats — for patterns that might 
indicate the early stages of a bio-attack. There was a brief 
scare: the system noticed a surge in flulike symptoms at 
military clinics. Thankfully, tests confirmed it was just that — 
the flu.
```

**The rest of the task is left as an exercise for the reader :)**

Comment: Thank you. I will try to understand and use this knowledge to solve my problem.